# Excel Custom Sorting multiple columns from a custom sort

Tags: excel, sorting

I have found some small examples but my problem seems to be out of my league.

I am trying to sort 2 columns at a time, based on the first 2 columns of the worksheet. The "reference" (first 2 columns) is in a specific order, colA being text and colB being a totals column.

I need the other columns of data (75 sets and counting) to match the reference sorting order, and move the totals of colB accordingly.

This is difficult because 1. the data is not alpha sorted, and 2. the sorting needs to be aligned to include spaces where there is no data recorded.  Like So

[http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=173518&s=f852c02850627105b9452dfa1169e3b0](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=173518&s=f852c02850627105b9452dfa1169e3b0/%22small%20version%22)

My understanding of coding is very limited, and I am struggling to figure out how to make the coding in the link applicable to my data.

What are the steps I should take to make this happen, for an ever growing data set?

Comment: Sounds quite confusing just with plain English. Can you post the current data structure and expected result so that it becomes easier for us to understand?

Comment: Sorry @YVXS, i tried to add pictures to show exactly whats going on but...... i dont have enough points or whatever.  Here's what I got

Comment: [starting data](http://imgur.com/ZKcPKBy/). And like the ozgrid link above, i need the data sorted by the reference order leaving blanks where no matches are found.

Comment: Figured out the solution to my own problem.  If i have a reference file, then there is a simple use of the Index/Match to find the total that is needed, then throw a IFERROR on the front to add in 0's where the data is not, and boom.  Sorry for the confusion all.